# High Charts - HTML in label

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

I created a pie chart with the high charts API. The pie chart has legends (label), and what i would like to do is add some html to the legends. For example, on of the labels for Microsoft, and i would like the legends to have a link ***with an icon*** next to its name. I have added the [use html](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.useHTML) feature mentioned in the High Charts doc's but i do not see the icon appearing in the legend. Does anyone know why this is?

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/k0utfqbs/3/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer <a href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></a>',
            y: 56.33
        }, {
            name: '<a href="https://www.google.com/" >Chrome</a>',
            y: 24.03
        }, {
            name: '<a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/" >Firefox</a>',
            y: 10.38
        }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
legend : {
    useHTML : true
},
```

That tells HighCharts that you would like to use HTML in the legend.

http://jsfiddle.net/k0utfqbs/6/